# Django UpdateView disable some fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have made a class view inheriting UpdateView. I have specified the fields and models from which the forms should be built. Now say if i have a field email, then I want to disable it in the form. I have no clues as to how it can be done.

```
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Users
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
    template_name = 'users_update_form.html'
    success_url = '/index/'
```

Comment: Do you want to *hide* it from the form? Or show it as a *readonly field*?

Comment: readonly field only

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To *hide* it:

```
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Users
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
    template_name = 'users_update_form.html'
```

In this case there is no need to create a separate `Form` class - as this is handled by the `UpdateView`.

To make the fiel *readonly*:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))

def clean_email(self):
    return self.initial['email']


class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Users
    form_class = UserForm
```

#### Note for Django 1.9

Django 1.9 has a [disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) option built in. Using this allows you to skip the additional `clean` method.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
    email = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
```

Comment: thanks.. earlier I tried using widget inside the Meta class and specified attrs for disabled to True. That didn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: Don't forget the `clean_email` method. Else the field would be readonly, but still possible to tamper it in the request.

Comment: In the `Meta` class of the Form or View?

Comment: In the Form `Meta` it should work as well: `widgets = {'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})}`

Comment: yes it worked there. Spelling mistake wrote 'widget'. My bad. Sometimes too much django forces you to commit such mistakes. lol

Answer (score 0):

Define a UserForm with exclude fields which you don't want to show in the form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        exclude = ('email',) # add fields to disable it in the form
```

If you want to make field readonly in > django 1.9
use [disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled)

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email =  forms.CharField(disabled=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date']
```

Then specify form in view.

```
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Users
    form_class = UserForm
    ....
```