# How to integrate a form into a Detail View?

Tags: django

**I would like to do:**

I am trying to create a form input on a detail view that will update a particular data column ('status') of the detailed model instance. Here is a picture of what I have in mind:
[image: status update selector]

The selector would display the current status and the user could change it and update from the detail view without having to access the UpdateView.

my idea here would be to have this happen:
1. On submit, get the new user entered value.
2. get the model instance of the currently detailed class
3. assign the model instance attribute as the user entered value
4. save the model instance

**I've tried**:   I don't know if this is the best way to do this but i've been trying to create an AJAX call, mostly by looking for examples online.

**Results**:  Terminal shows Post on submit: "[19/Nov/2019 17:50:33] "POST /task/edit/4 HTTP/1.1" 200 41256". However, the data is not saved to the db. On refresh, the selector returns to previously saved status.
The console shows: "script is connected", and "Update Status" with no errors. On submit, the alert displays success message: "127.0.0.1:8000 says status updated".

**Task_detail.html**

```
<div class="deliv-box edit">
  <form id="status-update-form" method='POST' action='{% url "task_edit" task.pk %}'>
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{task_form.status}}

    <input id="status-update-btn" type="submit" value="Update Status" />
  </form>
</div>

...

<script type="text/javascript">

  var frm = $('#status-update-form');
  frm.submit(function () {
      console.log("script is connected")
      console.log($('#status-update-btn').val())
      $.ajax({
          type: frm.attr('method'),
          url: frm.attr('action'),
          data: frm.serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
              $("#deliv-box edit").html(data);
              alert("status updated");
          },
          error: function(data) {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
      return false;
  });

</script>
```

**forms.py**

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = "__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
class TaskDetail(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name='task_detail.html'
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TaskDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['task_form'] = self.get_form
        return context

    def update(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            task_id = request.POST.get('id')
            task = Task.objects.get(pk = task_id)
            status_obj = request.POST.get('status')
            task.status = status_obj
            task.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status':'updated...'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status':'not updated'})
```

thank you.

**A solution:**
In the unlikely event that someone stumbles across this question and who is, like me, just trying to figure it out all by themselves, here is what I've learned about how this works: When a user wants to update a form, Django pre-populates the form with the existing data related to that instance. A user can then alter the data and re-submit the form.

Here, I was attempting to alter just one field of the exiting instance, but as I was only calling that one field, Django was assuming not, as I had hoped, that the other fields would remain the same, but that I intended the other fields to be submitted as blank. Where the fields are required one cannot return that field as blank. Therefore, Django was not able to validate the form and so the form did not get updated.

A solution that works is to call all the fields as hidden and show just the one you want to alter. This way Django can return the unaltered data and validate the form, and you get an update button on your detail view:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h4>  STATUS:  </h4>
       {% for field in form %}
       {{ field.as_hidden }}
       {% endfor %}
       {{form.status}}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the method `update` which does not exist, so it is never called.

You need to subclass `UpdateView` instead of the `DetailView` and the mixin.

```
class TaskUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name='task_detail.html'
    model = Task
    form_class = TaskForm
    # you can use the line below instead of defining form_class to generate a model form automatically
    # fields = ('status', )

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        # do anything here before you commit the save
        post.save()
        # or instead of two lines above, just do post = form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status':'updated...'})
```

Here is how you would add readonly (disabled) fields to your form:

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

   # override the default form field definitions for readonly fields
   other_field = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
   another_field = forms.IntegerField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ("status", "other_field", "another_field")
        # you could also just do:
        # fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: correct. that was a typo in transcription. thanks. fixed.

Comment: Ok, so if that is not the issue, can you post your `Task` model definition? also what is the value of `status_obj`? I would add prints to `update` to see what is happening.

Comment: thank you for your help here, and for clearing up a misconception i had about CBVs.  I understand your solution and it of course works to have an updateview. i was trying to update from the detail, which may not work. i tried to do it without ajax call, by splitting Formview and Detailview ala Django docs, but that didn't work. The problem with both strategies (as recognized in your solution too) is that Django does not see the form as associated with instance called in the detail view (as i hoped it would), it is set up to see it as an empty form, redirection disassociates and data is lost...

Comment: ... django will not allow mixing of updateview and detailview. So, i dont know if its possible to pass the detail instance pk to the form to any effect. for instance to prefill the form fields as hidden  allowing user to update the status field only?  not sure if that would work. I'll keep tinkering with it... for now i'll just implement a button to the updateview which will work fine. thanks again.

Comment: Yes, because you want to edit fields, you need to have an UpdateView. You can disable fields in the Form class to make them readonly (both server side and client side). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960590/856647 and the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled