# Django 3.0.8 Field.disable UpdateView

Tags: django, django-forms

For example I have a EntryUpdateForm that inherits from UpdateView that updates some data on a model. Now I'd like to disable certain fields. From the [Django documentiation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#disabled) I'm not sure where exatcly to put the Field.disable attribute to disable a certain field on a form.

**forms.py**

```
class EntryUpdateForm(UpdateView):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ["material", "shape", "diameter", "taken_from", "moved_to", "quantity"]
```

**views.py**

```
class EntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, EntryUpdateForm):
    model = Entry
    fields = ["material", "shape", "diameter", "taken_from", "moved_to", "quantity"]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I'm not even sure if it's possible to do this if I'm inheriting from the UpdateView, at least easly.

Comment: this should answer your question completely https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959866/django-updateview-disable-some-fields

Comment: This did the trick. In forms.py I added a new EntryForm class and added `material = forms.ChoiceField(disabled=True)` and then in views.py I added form_class = EntryForm and that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from mursalin I managed to get it to work.

**forms.py**

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ["material", "shape",  "diameter", "taken_from", "moved_to", "quantity"]

    material = forms.ChoiceField(disabled=True)
    shape = forms.ChoiceField(disabled=True)
    diameter= forms.CharField(disabled=True)  # add whichever field you want to disable


class EntryUpdateForm(UpdateView):

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

**views.py**

```
class EntryUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, EntryUpdateForm):
    model = Entry
    form_class = EntryForm  # pass the form in the view to get it to change

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class EntryUpdateForm(UpdateView):
    material =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'True'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = ["material", "shape", "diameter", "taken_from", "moved_to", "quantity"]
```

Replace material with whichever field you want to disable and use the appropriate widget

Comment: I don't know why but using widgets like in your example doesn't work for some reason